# How to convert one csv column into n csv files which contain equal rows and each file contains header as id?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a CSV file that contains only one column like

```
file.csv
id
c108258e-7feb-46f3-a225-b35bde591463
c4f5bbd3-8576-4201-b297-23b25ff82295
cfcfb84a-0525-4590-b428-fef177172030
9736f570-d1d9-4701-a2c4-6644b0570b4e
e45647a9-fe22-446b-a1c6-5870144d60cc
1782d947-a95c-4817-b809-152bdbf6574d
```

And I want to convert it into 3 CSV files that contain id as a header in each file.

```
file1.csv
id
c108258e-7feb-46f3-a225-b35bde591463
c4f5bbd3-8576-4201-b297-23b25ff82295

 
file2.csv
id
cfcfb84a-0525-4590-b428-fef177172030
9736f570-d1d9-4701-a2c4-6644b0570b4e


file3.csv
id
e45647a9-fe22-446b-a1c6-5870144d60cc
1782d947-a95c-4817-b809-152bdbf6574d
```

Please solve this using awk or sed only not jq?

Comment: *want to convert it into 4 CSV files* then why your desired output shows only 3 files? Would be number of lines in input always divisble by 4? If not should happen i.e. how to decide how many lines each file should have?

Answer (score 0):

Awk code:

```
NR == 1 { id = $0 }
NR > 1 { file = "file-" int(NR / 2)
         if (old_file != file)
         { close(old_file);
           old_file = file;
           print id > file }
         print $0 > file }
```

Records in Awk are numbered starting from 1. If the first record is an ID, and we want to assign the subsequent pairs of records to consecutive natural numbers, we simply divide the record number by 2, and truncate to integer: `int(NR/2)` maps records 2 and 3 to 1, 4 and 5 to 2, and so forth.

We collect the `id` from the fist record, and then for all subsequent records, we write the record to a `file-N` where `N` is the `int(NR/2)` file number.

Whenever we change from one file to another, we must close the previous file, otherwise if the input is long, the Awk process could reach the limit on the number of open files.

When changing to a new file, we also remember to print the `id` number into it first.